# Unable To Delete Multi Selected Objects

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to select mutiple objects by pressing SHIFT key, then by right click and select the delete option, it shall be able to delete all the selected objects.

However, it didn't work.

My code are as follow.

**MouseClick**

```
clickShape = null;
int x = clickEvent.getX(); // x-coordinate of point where mouse was
                                        // clicked
int y = clickEvent.getY(); // y-coordinate of point
        // when press down shift key
if (clickEvent.isShiftDown()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
        Shape s = (Shape) shapes.get(i);
        if (s.containsPoint(x, y)) {
            s.setColor(Color.RED);
            multiShape.add(s);

        }

    }
```

**DeleteSelection**

```
else if (command.equals("Delete Selection")) {
        for (Shape s : multiShape)// look for multishape size
            shapes.remove(multiShape);
}// remove selectedmultiple object.
```

Comment: It's much more useful to retrieve the id of the object then the object co-ordinates to delete. Also, after delete, you must call repaint.

Comment: It is possible that Shape area is zero and never contains any point. Try to find closest shape to your click and if its close enough add to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
shapes.remove(s);
```

not

<strike>`shapes.remove(multiShape);`</strike>

you should pass `shape s` to remove method to remove `shape s` from shapes `ArrayList`

```
java.util.ArrayList.remove(Object) // this is the method you are using .
```

Comment: Hi, it worked.I just marked as answer :-) Thanks alot.

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed that sometimes my deletion din work well.
For example, i'm able to delete selected object but failed to do so at another attempt.. :-(

Comment: @LattaLiPong that's may cause some other code ...basically above method remove object s from shapelist .there is no problem with that.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is, I will only able to delete the selection if the first shape I clicked earlier was chosen.

Comment: For example, there are 3 shapes. So i shift-click on Shape A,B,C respectively. However, if i right-click for the deletion selection on either B or C.. it would delete any except I click back onto Shape A

Comment: "it would delete any except I click back onto Shape A" plz again clarify this statement i didn't get it

Comment: Meaning to say, if I were to select 3 shapes at a time..Supposed I shall be able to perform the deletion on any shapes regardless its order. For example,i first click shape 1, then 2 and followed by 3. But, at this moment, with 3 selected objects, I have to click the Shape 1 to be able to perform the deletion.

Comment: @LattaLiPong where is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87506/discussion-between-latta-li-pong-and-fast-snail).